# Swap Column of Data in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database table with 6 columns of 365 rows of data. I need to swap the 3rd column (named 'Date_line') with new data while leaving the other 5 columns in place, without exporting the whole table, but can't get phpMyAdmin to work with me.

Normally I'd just truncate the table and upload a revised CSV file for the whole table, but here's the catch: I have to update 232 data tables with this same exact column of data (the column data is common to all 232 tables). To do all 232 individually would mean exporting each table, opening it in Excel, swapping the old column for the new one, converting to CSV then re-uploading. It would be a lot easier if I could just import a single column CSV to overwrite the old one. But I don't know how.

I'd like to do this using the phpMyAdmin interface... I'm not much experienced in assigning scripts. Is there a way?

Comment: Is the data for your third column same? or different value per row?

Comment: if the data in the csv is the same for all tables, then load it into a temp table, then use that temp table to update everything else. one import, lots of `update`s. much easier than a ton of imports/overwrites.

Comment: Latheesan: The data of the third column is the date marker for each of the 365 rows (each row is a calendar day), so each row is different. But the entire column for all 232 tables is an exact duplicate of those 365 rows. I need to be able to swap out only that third column in each table with a new updated one.

Comment: Marc: Yeah, that would be easier, but can it be done so with one column is replaced out of a six-column table?